# Is it possible to add a background image to the scroll-bounce area in html?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, overflow

Most browsers support **scroll-bouncing** on websites so that when you scroll to the top or bottom of a website it "bounces", instead of abruptly stopping.

Normally the extra area exposed when the page "bounces" is plain white, but you can apply a background-color element to the **<html>** tag, and this extra area will take on that color(You can see this described, and in action here: [Example Site](https://www.tempertemper.net/blog/scroll-bounce-page-background-colour))

Here you can see the scroll-bouncing with a custom color, instead of the white:
[image]

The effect I want to achieve is that when the page bounces, the scroll-bounce area has a background-image, instead of just plain color. I think this effect could look nice with some simple icons tiled with the branding of the site. I remember seeing this effect a few years ago on [css-tricks.com](https://css-tricks.com/), but I don't know how the effect was achieved, or if the way it was done has since been deprecated.

From what I understand, it's not possible to add a background-image property to the **<html>** tag, but is this possible through a work-around? Perhaps cancelling out scroll-bounce behavior with the overscroll-behavior property, and creating a similar looking effect with javascript when you scroll above or below the edges of the page?

Comment: Add it to the body instead, and use a wrapper for the remaining content, if it needs to be different. Make sure to not apply a background to the html when doing so.

Comment: @prettyInPink This works perfectly for me. If you put it as an answer I will mark it as the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will work (as i haven't tried it), but you can take an image element with `position: absolute/fixed` (absolute or fixed depending on where your img tag is placed) and set - `bottom: <height of the image>` and `left: 0`. This way the image technically exists above the viewport and will only by visible if you tried to scroll past the navbar which will cause the bounce effect.